# Python: issue with calling methods

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and  I've written a class for managing a simple phonebook. (I've removed the methods that aren't relevant to this post).

```
class Phonebook:

    def __init__(self):
        self.book = {}

    def newEntry(self, name, number):
        self.book[name] = number

    def findNumber(self, name):
        return self.book[name]

    def nameList(self):
        list = self.book.keys()
        list.sort()
        for k in list:
            print k, self.book[k]
```

My question concerns the last method, `nameList`, which prints the phonebook entries (name and phone no.) in alphabetical order. Originally, I tried the following:

```
 def nameList(self):
        list = self.book.keys()
        list.sort()
        for k in list:
            print k, findNumber(k)
```

However, this threw up a "NameError" global name 'findNumber' is not defined" error. Would someone be able to explain why this didn't work?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't name your variables `list`, it's already the name of the built-in list type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work because `findNumber` is not a globally defined function.  It's a method on your object, so to call it, you would need to invoke `self.findNumber(k)`.

So your example would look like:

```
 def nameList(self):
        list = self.book.keys()
        list.sort()
        for k in list:
            print k, self.findNumber(k)
```

Comment: No problem!  If this did solve your problem, could you [mark my answer accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#link-howtoask)?  Thanks!

Comment: Done.  :)  It wouldn't let me accept your answer before a few minutes had passed.

Answer (score 1):

`findNumber(k)` should be accessed as `self.findNumber(k)` when inside class.

or as `Phonebook.findNumber(self,k)`.

because a `variable` or `function` declared under a class becomes a class's `attribute`.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `self` to `findNumber()`

so it would become:

```
def nameList(self):
        list = self.book.keys()
        list.sort()
        for k in list:
            print k, self.findNumber(k)
```

else it doesn't know where `findNumber` is coming from because it is only defined in your class, or, self.